# proguard can't find reference method

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

how can i solve this warnings ?

the "invoke" method referenced below,

```
public final native Object invoke(Object[] paramArrayOfObject) throws Throwable;
```

so, i must ignore this (just my opinion). but ignorewarnings are not helpful

does anybody knows how ignore this warnings?

```
ProGuard, version 4.9
Reading program jar [C:\Users\Las Plagas\Desktop\wbsys.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
Warning: WebAnalysisMain: can't find referenced method 'void invoke(java.lang.Class)' in class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
     Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
     You may need to recompile the code or update the library versions.
     Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
     '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: Taking a look in MethodHandle api, there's no `invoke` method that returns void. But in the method signature you provided there's nothing to do with returning void. Can you provide more of your code and the proguard script?

Comment: @JeanWaghetti many thanks to you. i thought that proguard configuration was wrong. but actually my code(handle return parameter) was wrong.